# ORC schema evolution

Tags: hadoop, hive, schema, orc

After going through a sample ORC file itself I came to know that ORC file format does not store any column information, in fact all the column names will be replaced by _c0 to _cn, in such scenario how a proper schema evolution can be achieved for ORC tables?

Answer (score 1):

ORC format does not store any information about hive column names. There was a bug which was storing column information if ORC file were created using `PIG`. You can find the details below

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7189

I think ORC file format (and other) rely on `Hive Metastore` for this information. if you will run `describe formatted <table_name>`, you will get the schema information.

something like

```
# col_name              data_type               comment

name                    string
```

Comment: Agreed. But the point was regarding schema evolution. Suppose if we are using a parquet file which actually allows the user to store schema has all the column information, incase of modification of columns  this file can be used, how can we achieve this functionality in hive ORC files?